# Understanding wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI

Tags: wxpython

I'm trying to follow the below piece of code from a book, but I am having trouble understanding it. I was hoping someone could help clarify the following issues:

- When I don't anything in the textctrl, the has_sel is set to false but how does the IF stmt gets executed?
- What is event_id? Is it the event_id for the whole Menubar?
- Why would the event_id change when the items in the txt_ctrl are changed?
- When event.Enable(has_sel) is true, how are both the buttons enabled/disabled?

Here is the code:

```
import wx

ID_CHECK_ITEM = wx.NewId()

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TextFrame, self).__init__(parent,
                                        *args,
                                        **kwargs)

        # Attributes
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.txtctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel,
                                   value="Hello World",
                                   style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self.txtctrl, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.CreateStatusBar() # For output display

        # Menu
        menub = wx.MenuBar()
        editm = wx.Menu()
        editm.Append(wx.ID_COPY, "Copy\tCtrl+C")
        editm.Append(wx.ID_CUT, "Cut\tCtrl+X")
        editm.Append(ID_CHECK_ITEM, "Selection Made?",
                     kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        menub.Append(editm, "Edit")
        self.SetMenuBar(menub)

        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, self.OnUpdateEditMenu)

    def OnUpdateEditMenu(self, event):
        event_id = event.GetId()
        sel = self.txtctrl.GetSelection()
        print("Start")
        print('Sel',sel)
        has_sel = sel[0] != sel[1]
        print('has_sel=',has_sel)
        print('sel[0]=',sel[0])
        print('sel[1]=',sel[1])
        print('event_id=',event_id)
        print('wx.ID_COPY',wx.ID_COPY)
        print('wx.ID_CUT=',wx.ID_CUT)
        print('ID_CHECK_ITEM=',ID_CHECK_ITEM)
        if event_id in (wx.ID_COPY, wx.ID_CUT):
            print("Select option set to true-1")
            event.Enable(has_sel)
        elif event_id == ID_CHECK_ITEM:
            print("Select option set to true-2")
            event.Check(has_sel)
        else:
            event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a tutorial. Since you got this code from a book, I'm going to guess that the same book should contain an explanation of the code. That is the first place you should be looking.

Next, it may be helpful to look at the [documentation for wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.UpdateUIEvent-class.html) to get a better understanding of what this event does and what it's methods are. The documentation says that this event triggers to "give an application the chance to update various user interface elements". For example when you open a menu, the menu must be drawn but the whole application doesn't need to update.

Now for your questions:

**1. When I don't anything in the textctrl, the has_sel is set to false but how does the IF stmt gets executed?**
Actually, you aren't checking what's in the textctrl, you're checking what it *highlighted*. The method being called is `GetSelection()`. Looking at the [wx.TextCtrl documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TextCtrl-class.html) we can see that this method returns the starting and ending index of the highlighted (or "selected") text. Obviously, if the start and the end are in the same place then no selection is made. To get the actual text we need to call `GetValue()`. Of course, if the textctrl is empty then you can't select any text!

As for the second part of your question, the selected text has nothing to do with the if statement. The if statement is only checking for the event's ID (I will explain below), not the selection. What the selection **is** used for is to decide whether Copy and Cut should be enabled or not but the value of `has_sel` does not affect the if statement at all.

**2. What is event_id? Is it the event_id for the whole Menubar?**
In WxPython, you tell objects apart using their IDs. For example, if I have two buttons, "Save" and "Cancel", you want them to perform different actions when clicked. If we only use `wx.EVT_BUTTON` then we can't tell the buttons apart since both buttons create that event. This is where IDs come in handy. As you can see in your code, events have a `GetID()` method. This returns the ID of the object that created the event. So using this, and if we know the IDs of "Save" and "Cancel", we can check which button the user clicked.

In the case of `wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI`, `GetID()` will return the ID of the object that is updating. It is **not** an ID for the event itself. In your code, it's the items inside `editm` are updating. See how each item has it's own ID? This leads us to...

**3. Why would the event_id change when the items in the txt_ctrl are changed?**
Looking at my previous answer, you should be able to answer this question yourself. The event has nothing to do with the textctrl. Yes, we're *checking* in the selection of the textctrl, but that isn't what's causing the event. What is happening is the individual items in `editm` that are trying to update, so each item sends it's own `wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI`. The ID changes based on which menu item sent the event.

**4. When event.Enable(has_sel) is true, how are both the buttons enabled/disabled?**
If you look at the [wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI documentation](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.UpdateUIEvent-class.html) you see that `Enable(enable)` uses the event's ID to enable or disable the appropriate menu item. `has_sel` is `True` only when text is selected, thus `event.Enable(has_sel)` will enable the object that created the event if text is selected and disable it otherwise. Remember that both "Copy" and "Cut" create their own separate `wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI` events so `Enable(has_sel)` is called on both menu items.

Comment: Great..You're clarification that events will be called for each items solved most of the understanding..Thanks once again